# CSS how can I make text appear next to an image on hover instead of on it?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure out how I can make a block of text appear to the side of an image when hovered over instead of appearing on top of it, however I can't seem to find any explanations for anything other than having the text fade in on the actual image itself. This is what I've been experimenting with(adapted from w3schools), as of right now it only has the text on the image. If anyone could edit it so that the text comes to the side that would be incredibly helpful.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="placeholder" class="image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">This should be to the side of the image</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the text to be outside of the image.

You are using `position: relative` on the `.container`, that's why the `.middle` will stay inside of it, removing that will solve the issue:

```css
.container {
  /* position: relative; */
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center; */
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="placeholder" class="image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">This should be to the side of the image</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! That is exactly what I was hoping to do with it!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Check if that's what you need (made myself a quick example) :

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.leftBlock {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.leftBlock:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  
}

.leftBlock:hover + .rightBlock {
  opacity: 1;
}

.rightBlock {
  right: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3683056/pexels-photo-3683056.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="leftBlock">
  <div class="rightBlock">Text Goes Here</div>
</div>
```